# find the geolocation of the server in android

Tags: geolocation

If I have an IP address how do I find the geolocation of the ip address?
For example if I write an android application to download an image and I find out the IP address of the server hosting the image, how to program the application to find the physical location of the server?

Comment: Not sure how to manage in Android Native code  But this is the link for that purpose http://ipinfodb.com/ip_location_api.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you wont be getting too close locations with IP Address address, you could try finding more REST services, such as http://freegeoip.net/, with those you would use normal HTTP GET with the IP-address and get the city name as reply.

Then if you want to show that on map, you could of course use Geo coding services to get the coordinates for the city, and show the user the location with a map.